# Procedures with tables t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I am testing one procedure with one table.

My procedure:

{

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateAge] 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @today datetime, @thisYearBirthDay datetime, @dayOfBirth datetime 
DECLARE @years int, @months int, @days int Declare @y nvarchar(10), @m nvarchar(10), @d nvarchar(10)    
Declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @b varchar(100) 

SET @dayOfBirth = ( SELECT top 1 birth from emp) 

SELECT @today = GETDATE() 
SELECT @thisYearBirthDay = DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @dayOfBirth, @today), @dayOfBirth) 
SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(year, @dayOfBirth, @today) - (CASE WHEN @thisYearBirthDay > @today THEN 1 ELSE      0 END) 
SELECT @months = MONTH(@today - @thisYearBirthDay) - 1 
SELECT @days = DAY(@today - @thisYearBirthDay) - 1 
SET @b = cast(@dayOfBirth as varchar(100))
SET @y = cast(@years as nvarchar(10)) 
SET @m = cast(@months as nvarchar(10)) 
SET @d = cast(@days as nvarchar(10)) 
SET @sql = N'select Name, birth, '+@y+' as [Metai], '+@m+' as [Menuo], '+@d+' as [Diena] from emp' 
exec sp_executesql @sql 
end
```

}
And my table info from emp:

```
1 BASAVARAJ BIRADAR 1985-04-11 00:00:00.000 NULL NULL NULL 
2 SHREE BIRADAR     2013-01-25 00:00:00.000 NULL NULL NULL
```

After execute this procedure `Exec CalculateAge` I got:

```
BASAVARAJ BIRADAR 1985-04-11 00:00:00.000 28 9 18 
SHREE BIRADAR     2013-01-25 00:00:00.000 28 9 18
SET @dayOfBirth = ( SELECT top 1 birth from emp) 
I can use only one value, if I remove "top 1" I get error
```

How to make it that I should this result after procedure `Exec CalculateAge` :

```
BASAVARAJ BIRADAR 1985-04-11 00:00:00.000 28 9 18 
SHREE BIRADAR     2013-01-25 00:00:00.000 1 0 2
```

I want to calculate every birth colummn from emp table with this procedure for two way:

1. Only execute this procedure
2. Insert EXEC procedure restuls into table emp into new columm a, b, c of each rows

Comment: Please try reformatting this question so that the code is readable. I'd assumed the lost formatting was due to you just not hitting the `{}` button on your code sample, but your code is exactly as unreadable if we apply that. Line breaks and indentation would help a lot - then hit the `{}` button so that we can read it as code.

Comment: What could help to me to write the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to use a variable (i.e., @dayofbirth) to calculate age for each employee using a query that selects only the Top 1 birthdate. This is because your variable requires a single value for the entire procedure, while you want a single birthdate value for each employee, which is not specified in your current select statement. To make this work, you would have to pass a value into your procedure, such as an employee ID, that would bring back just the employee's birthdate for the desired employee.

Now, you may have a good reason for using a stored procedure to calculate age, but there are simpler ways to calculate age. The calculation below took 1.4 seconds to calculate age for 150,000 rows, which includes delays for network traffic and such. Also, it is an exact way of calculating someone's age in years as of the current system time. We use this calculation on all of our systems, including Dashboards which require very quick response time for end-users.

```
Select ID
    , (DATEDIFF(YY, DOB.BIRTHDATE, GETDATE()) - 
    Case
        When( (MONTH(DOB.BIRTHDATE)*100
                + DAY(DOB.BIRTHDATE)) > (MONTH(GETDATE())*100 
                + DAY(GETDATE())) ) 
            Then 1 
            Else 0 
        End) as Age
```

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your issue and was the best answer you received, please be sure to mark it as the answer. If it didn't help your issue, feel free to comment about what additional help you need.